# How to append react component into specific div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I receive html as string from the backend:

```
'<div><p>Example<p><div>'
```

Then I parse it using html-react-parser.
What I am trying to do afterwards, is to replace every table that I receive with my SmartTable component. As I understand, it would take following steps:

1. Parse all data from tables
2. Replace all tables with div containers with specified ids for each table
3. Append SmartTable components into corresponding divs

I've done first two steps, but cant figure out the third.

Is it possible to acheive this in react?